# Upload a file through my application in IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am creating an application in IBM Bluemix. I need to upload a local file to the server through my application. What services can I use? Please also suggest any tutorials to learn basic application creation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

@sasirekha, welcome to Stack Overflow. Although I appreciate your need to get help getting started with Bluemix, Stack Overflow is a forum for technical programming questions; you need to explain what you have already tried, and include some code. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

[Bluemix Essentials](https://developer.ibm.com/courses/all-courses/bluemix-essentials/) is a good getting-started tutorial. You can find many others on YouTube, GitHub and IBM developerWorks. Please ask any other getting-started questions on [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/).